# Is it possible to change the path where srt file grow? - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am getting below error where its actually giving out of disk. This is because of allocated space for srt file generation is not enough. so we decided to change the path with huge space..Is it possible to change it through program?

**SYSTEM ERROR: I/O error 0 in writeto, ret 2048, file 56(/mfgtmp/tmp/srtE5yybD), addr 77010944. (290)**

Answer (score 5):

The -T startup parameter defines the folder for temporary files like srt files.

https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-manage-applications-117/page/Distributing-temporary-files.html